# Display featured products by category

Tags: posts, woocommerce-offtopic

I have this code in my themes' shortcode to display featured product rating product like this. But I need to get product by category show. Which code do I have to add. Any suggestions?

```
if($type == 'featured'){

        /**********QUERY FOR FEATURED PRODUCT**********/

        $query_args = array('posts_per_page' => $number, 'no_found_rows' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'product' );



        $query_args['meta_query'] = array();



        $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(

            'key' => '_featured',

            'value' => 'yes'

        );

        $query_args['meta_query'][] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();

        $query_args['meta_query'][] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();

        /**********END QUERY FOR FEATURED PRODUCT**********/

    }elseif($type == 'top-rated'){

        /**********QUERY FOR TOP-RATED PRODUCT**********/

        add_filter( 'posts_clauses',  array( $woocommerce->query, 'order_by_rating_post_clauses' ) );



        $query_args = array('posts_per_page' => $number, 'no_found_rows' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'product' );



        $query_args['meta_query'] = array();



        $query_args['meta_query'][] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();

        $query_args['meta_query'][] = $woocommerce->query->visibility_meta_query();

        /**********END QUERY FOR TOP-RATED PRODUCT**********/
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to determine from what category you want to display those products. If this happends on a single post display, you can get all post's categories via [wp_get_object_terms function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

```
global $post;
$query_args[ 'category__in' ] = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
```

If this happens on a archive page, you can get the category id from query vars:

```
$query_args[ 'cat' ] = get_query_var('cat');
```

Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters for more details.